# Reduce Terragrunt console output

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

Terragrunt outputs hundreds of lines of text like:

```
[terragrunt] 2020/12/14 08:55:27 Setting download directory for module /module/name to /module/name/.terragrunt-cache
```

and

```
[terragrunt] [/module/name ] 2020/12/14 08:55:27 Module /module/name  must wait for 1 dependencies to finish
```

Is there any way of quietening this output and only seeing the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no builtin option to do it. There is [opened issue](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/432) for that. But since `terragrunt` logs everything into `stderr`, you can workaround it by [redirecting](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/432#issuecomment-371467507) `terragrunt` logs:

```
terragrunt apply 2>/dev/null
```